# Spring and Grails webflow

Tags: spring, grails, spring-webflow-2

I've got an app that has quite a lot of Spring Webflow XML already written for it. My team is moving to grails (which I'm new to) for our next app and I was wondering if anyone knew if there was an easy way to get a grails app to play nice with the Spring Webflow xml.

I know about the groovy webflow DSL and would prefer not to rewrite everything for a variety of reasons.